# OTLP doesn't trace multiple activity sources to AppInsight

Tags: asp.net-core, trace, open-telemetry

I'm having trouble making a POC using multiple ActivitySource using dedicated source names to emulate a potential instrumentation library.
My setup is as follow

```
services.AddOpenTelemetry()
        .WithTracing(traceBuilder =>
        {
            traceBuilder
                .AddConsoleExporter()

                .AddSource(openTelemetryOptions.ApplicationName)
                .AddSource(nameof(ActivityTracedClass))

                .ConfigureResource(resourceBuilder => resourceBuilder.AddService(openTelemetryOptions.ApplicationName))
                .ConfigureResource(resourceBuilder => resourceBuilder.AddService(nameof(ActivityTracedClass)))

                .ConfigureInstrumentation(services, openTelemetryOptions)
                .ConfigureExporter(openTelemetryOptions);
        });
```

Up until now I only used an ActivitySource declared like this

```
 using var source = new ActivitySource(ApplicationName!);
 using var tracedActivity = source.StartActivity(name: activityName ?? memberName);
```

everytime I need to start tracing some code or function, which was working fine; I get to see my traces and span as expected in appInsight.

Now I'm trying to simulate an instrumentation package using an ActivitySource declared like this somewhere

```
ActivitySource activitySource = new(nameof(ActivityTracedClass), "1.0.0");
var activity = activitySource.StartActivity();
```

called everytime I would like to trace code with this other ActvitySource.

My porblem is I see absolutely nothing in AppInsight, or the console export, comming from this second ActivitySource.
In my example traced test code, I verfied that both activitySource create an activity, indicating that a listener exists, but that's as far as it goes.
I still do see activities coming from the ActivitySource called openTelemetryOptions.ApplicationName, that's not broken.

I used the doc from [OpenTelemetry GitHub](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/docs/trace/extending-the-sdk/README.md#instrumentation-library) and [NpgSql GitHub](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/b4974532f2c0482470885434201c7be4ac60569e/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlActivitySource.cs#L9) to replicate the "right way" of doing this but something is missing and I can't find out what. From what I read, adding a source in TraceProviderBuilder, and creating an ActivitySource (static or not) sharing the same name is pretty much all they do when you ignore the IOC setup for the instrumenting classes.

One thing I'm sure I'm not doing right is the usage of .ConfigureResource(). I don't relally understand what this does, some packages seems to do it, some don't. If anyone has insight on this I'd like to understand that part.

**EDIT**

I removed the second ConfigureResource and added the SetSampler() but that wasn't the issue.
So resorted to copy pasted all executed code side by side to find what could be wrong; And I saw the issue. This is how I used the two activities :

```
    using var activitySource = new ActivitySource(nameof(ActivityTracedClass));
    using var activity = activitySource.StartActivity(nameof(ActivityTracedClass) + "-Activity");

    await Task.Delay(150);
    activity!.AddEvent(new ActivityEvent("waited fro 150ms"));

    var source = new ActivitySource(ActivityTracker.ApplicationName!);
    var tracedActivity = source.StartActivity(name: ActivityTracker.ApplicationName! + "-Activity");

    Thread.Sleep(50);
    tracedActivity!.AddEvent(new ActivityEvent("waited for 50 ms"));
```

The difference being in the **using** surrounding the fist activity and not the second one.
I tested it, and it was my issue.

Looking back at it, it should have been obvious from this line in [Git readme](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/docs/trace/customizing-the-sdk/README.md):

> Exporters expose hooks for exporting batches of completed Activity instances (a batch may contain a single or many records) and are called by processors.

key word being **completed** which I know now means disposed.

Thanks for the sugestions.

Comment: You're right on the configureResource, service is something that happens at the application level so the second is overriding the first.  Your code looks fine. What I would do is add a ConsoleExporter to rule out AppInsights in the first instance, then add .SetSampler<AlwaysOnSampler>() to see if that helps. The code looks functionally correct to me, as long ActivityTracedClass is the same in both the ActivitySource and AddSource, also maybe try with hardcoded strings to start.

Comment: Missed that you'd do console. My only suggestion would be hardcoded string names (versions not required) and adding the sampler.

Answer (score 0):

Explained in the question edit : The activity needs to be disposed to be caught up by the exporter. use a "using" or dispose of it manually but you need to take care of it.